# SEO impact of using regional TLDs like .me

Tags: seo, domains, top-level-domains

It is common that people use regional TLDs with a fake meaning to register a good-looking website. A famous example is `.me`, which is popularly offered by most of registrars alongside generic domains.

As far as I know, search engines somehow weight the regional websites. For example, a `.ca` is supported to be targeted in Canada. I understand that search engines are adjusted to the market popularity, but I am curious, if a regional TLD such as `.me` is considered as a generic TLD when targeting globally?

In general, my question is that how much `TLD` affects the SEO for global audience?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although [.me](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.me)  is a [country code top-level domain (ccTLD)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Country_code_top-level_domain), it has been one of the fastest-growing and widely used in [history](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.me#Sunrise.2C_land_rush.2C_and_open_registration_periods). Consequently it's considered to be generic enough to use for targeting a global audience, as discussed by Matt Cutts [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GY65Mlgw124) (~1:34).

In the case with `.me` therefore, it should be treated as equally by search engines as [generic top-level domains (gTLD)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_top-level_domain), for example:  `.com`, `.info`, `.net`, and `.org`.