# Impact of using free domain extension for personal email (spam-wise)

Tags: email, spam, spam-prevention

Certain TLDs/extensions are allowed to be registered for free. Examples include: .tk and .ml

Say for example, I register `somedomain.tk` as my personal domain for email ***only***.

I use Google Apps (for email hosting) and register: `capistan@somedomain.tk`

What impact, with regards to being flagged for spam, will I experience for using a .tk or .ml or any other free domain extension?

Is spam only determined via IP address or do certain domain extensions (.tk , .ml , etc.) also carry with them negative-opinions from spam-engines?

Comment: The TLD should not matter. Spam is determined by two things, the IP address having a prior history and the content of the e-mail itself.

Comment: As usual closetnoc is right on point. And the crazy part is when ip addresses are flagged being that some ip's have a few thousand websites(domains) associated with them. If people end up receiving email and place you in a contact list or label the email as not spam it helps battling the categorized as spam via ip.

Comment: `.tk` domains have historically been linked to [spam abuse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.tk#Abuse) as I covered [here](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/53563/how-easily-recognized-are-new-tlds/53570#53570). Although IP's are traditionally used, many ISP's have added filters, including blocking [DNS lookups](https://community.sophos.com/products/unified-threat-management/f/network-protection-firewall-nat-qos-ips/80087/indicator-compromise-suspicious-tk-dns-query/305421?pi2132219849=20). It might be OK for personal use, but you can buy a gTLD for less than a US dollar.

Comment: While certain TLDs are well know for spam and bad activity, the only place I have seen a TLD penalized in some fashion right out of the gate is in search, though that does not seem to be done anymore, that is, short of domain trust scores.

Comment: @closetnoc One only has to search on [.tk + spam](https://www.google.com/search?q=spam+assasin#q=%22.tk%22+%2B+spam) to see that it's commonly being abused and blocked (like in the link I provided). In fact, the registry for `.tk` freely admits it [here](http://www.dot.tk/en/report_abuse.html): `Dot TK is a very open service, available for everyone in all countries. Because of this we are also used by fraudsters—and we are very aware of this...`.  I wouldn't recommend for anyone to use this for their email, unless they don't really care if it gets through reliably or not.

Comment: @dan I learned something new today. Thanks!! Now that's enough - I am tired. ;-) I can only bit stream at 1k per week.